# tenses with "until recently"

Tags: grammar

Which one is correct? If all are correct, do they mean different things?

> We **haven't eaten** at home until recently.
>
> We **didn't eat** at home until recently.
>
> We **hadn't eaten** at home until recently.

Hi everyone, I think 'past perfect tense' and 'simple past tense' both are natural because it implies that I have now eaten at home But I am not sure. Is present perfect also correct? And when should I use present perfect with *until recently*?

I don't understand how to use "until recently". I would be grateful if you could help me understand the rule of using "until recently".

Answer (score 1):

"Until recently" is an unspecified point in past, not long before now. But from the perspective of writing, it can be also considered the present time ([Grammar Exchange](https://thegrammarexchange.infopop.cc/topic/tense-with-until-recently)). So, you can use present perfect and various forms of past tense to describe "not eating at home" from slightly different aspects.

> 1. We haven't eaten at home until recently.

This is in present perfect and means we haven't have a habit to eat at home until "now."

---

> 2. We didn't eat at home until recently.

This is in past simple and means we didn't eat at home one single time until recently.

---

> 3. We hadn't eaten at home until recently.

This is in past perfect and means we had never eaten at home until recently. It basically means same as in the past tense.

---

You could also say:

> 4. We were not eating at home until recently

This is in past progressive and shows an ongoing action of not eating at home during a period of time until recently.

Answer (score 0):

@Andrew answered in a comment:

> "Recently" means "a short time ago". "Until recently" means "up to a short time ago". I'm sure these both easily translate. It seems more like your question is asking about the differences between the present perfect, simple past, and past perfect tenses.